# Handlebars and script with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, handlebars.js

I hope this would be clear enough and sorry for my bad English.

I have a node js server. The server should load configuration from DB and get a template from remote source and render the template with the configuration loaded.

The template is pretty simple HTML page with some `onclick` events.

I choose the template engine to be Handlebars (I hope this right)

But this is my problem: I need all event listeners to be loaded from the remote source as well.

How do I do this? Can I put a script tag inside hbs file?
Is Handlebars was the right choice for me?

Comment: Where have you written event handlers? Can you add source HTML file, sample if not original, that you are getting from remote server?

Comment: @PratikGaikwad I didn't write them yet because im not sure how. I only have simple hbs file with some div and classes I get from remote source.
 from what I have read so far maybe pug(jade) is the right solution for me because then I can write inline javascript

Comment: Yes, you should add script tag either in `hbs` file or the string that you are receiving from the remote server